# Finding the count of each reaction from a post

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I want to be able to get the total amount of reactions and then split by each type of reaction. This is what I am using so far for getting the total amount of reactions and the count of likes.

```
 me?fields=posts{reactions.summary(true),likes.summary(true)}
```

However, I would like for the other kind of reactions to be included as well (love, sad, hahah etc.) 
When I try to query the love field I get the following debug message:

> The love field does not exist on the PagePost object.

I've gone through all the node options but I can't find them.
Any help will be greatly appreciated since I am quite stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific types of reactions can be queried using the `type` parameter, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v6.0/object/reactions#parameters

If you want to query data for multiple reactions in one request, then you will have to use the *Field Aliasing* syntax, otherwise you will get an error saying that your field list contained the reactions field twice. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/aliasing-fields

So this could look something like this,

```
me?fields=posts{reactions.type(LOVE).summary(1).as(reacts_love),
                reactions.type(LIKE).summary(1).as(reacts_like)}
```

(Exemplary for the two reaction types LOVE and LIKE - add the rest, by following the same format.)

The resulting data will then contain sub-structures under the keys `reacts_love` and `reacts_like`.

This might still give you some data about *individual* reactions - if you don’t need those, but only the summaries, you can also add `.limit(0)` into the above “chains” of parameters - then the `data` portion of these responses will always be empty.